# Unsigned Short Division for binary representation in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

So I am trying to do an integer division on a binary representation of an unsigned short. For example: Say the Unsigned Short x=5, the binary number representation is
1111. 7 would be 111. I want to be able to find the number of Pairs of the 1's bit representation. My idea was to count the number of 1's using bit manipulation as follows.

```
unsigned short divide(unsigned short input) {
    unsigned short count = 0;
    while (input != 0){
        if ((input & 1) == 1)
            count = count + 1;
        input = input >> 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The above code works for getting the total number of 1 bits in a binary representation. Example: in my 7, it would return 3 since there are 3 1's in the binary representation. Now I just want to be able to perform integer division such as 3/2=1 to find the number of 1 pairs. 3/2 for an unsigned short would be 1 since there are only 1 pair of 1's bits. if for 5, it would be 4/2=2. 2 pairs. How would I go about in terms of implementing a integer division without using arithmetic operations such as modulus, +,-,*,/.

Comment: I think you meant `x=15` instead of `x=5` for the first example.

Comment: Dividing by a power-of-2 is the same as a right shift when the dividend is an unsigned integer.

Comment: x/pow(2,y) is equal to x>>y

Comment: `only 1 pair of 1's bits` - as far as I understand, you'r algorithm will fail for `10101`. - has no 1's bits pairs, you will count 1 pair (3/2=1).